# function and its definition outside main doesnt work

Tags: c

I have this code from the "Sams teach yourself C" book and it just doesnt work with the function definition outside the main function (after the function). I have got this program to run by putting the function definition in the main function in the beginning.

Why cant my CodeBlocks program use the function definition when its coded exactly as in the smart C book that I am learning from?

The code from the book:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define TARGET_AGE 88

int year1, year2;

int calcYear(int year1);

int main( void )
{
    // Ask the user for the birth year
    printf( "What year was the subject born? ");
    printf( "Enter as a 4-digit year (YYYY): ");
    scanf( " %d", &year1);

    // Calculate the future year and display it
    year2 = calcYear(year1);

    printf( "Someone born in %d will be %d in %d.",
            year1, TARGET_AGE, year2);
    return 0;

    /* The function to get the future year */
    int calcYear(int year1)
    {
        return(year1+TARGET_AGE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the *declaration* `calcYear` is outside of `main`, you're attempting to nest the definition of `calcYear` function **inside** of the `main` function.  While some compilers accept this as an extension, many don't.  Even on those that do, in my experience it's of limited usefulness.

Move the definition of `calcYear` outside of `main`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define TARGET_AGE 88

int year1, year2;

int calcYear(int year1);

int main( void )
{
    // Ask the user for the birth year
    printf( "What year was the subject born? ");
    printf( "Enter as a 4-digit year (YYYY): ");
    scanf( " %d", &year1);

    // Calculate the future year and display it
    year2 = calcYear(year1);

    printf( "Someone born in %d will be %d in %d.",
            year1, TARGET_AGE, year2);
    return 0;
}

/* The function to get the future year */
int calcYear(int year1)
{
    return(year1+TARGET_AGE);
}
```

Comment: Yes, now I get it. I made a mistake when copying from the book. The function definition should be outside the main function. Thanks for the answer.